# Can't always select "Very low quality"

Tags: support, flagging, specific-flag

I have noticed that when reviewing flags on answers, I can't always select the "very low quality flag". Why is that?

Comment: If I recall correctly you can only choose low quality flags for non-positively voted posts.

Comment: [Some discussion of this restriction](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208604/251274).